# Samsung Gear S2 BLE central role is possible?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-gear

We are trying to connect Gear S2 with our custom BLE device. But we are unsuccessful to connect where as we can scan BLE devices using Tizen API.

So for test purpose I downloaded an application on android which made my android phone to act as peripheral and it broadcasted few characteristics BLE Peripheral Simulator [ https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral&hl=en]
Now i could connect to this characteristic using another Phone which listens to BLE devices.
In same scenario I replaced the listener Android APp with Samsung Gear S2 which had the code to listen and connect to this BLE device.
Gear S2 could successfully read the characteristics but it was unable to connect with the Peripheral application.

So I am doubtful if Gear S2 can act in a central role?
Any pointers would be really helpful.
Regards,
Shraddha

Comment: check https://developer.tizen.org/fr/forums/sdk-ide/bluetooth-api-wearable-devices?langswitch=fr

Comment: I have already posted there.

Comment: From your description its clear that you are able to read the characteristics that means Gear S2 is acting as central device. Now you need to find the correct API to connect with the other device. May I know you are using which API to connect with the peripheral device?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with updated Gear.